# .remplace con array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de remplazar un texto que tengo en un textarea según se seleccione algo en un select.

El caso es que lo que necesitaría es que borre el texto antiguo para insertar el nuevo, pero claro no puede borrar todo el texto solo una serie de textos que tengo almacenados en mysql. Esto es así por si acaso el usuario ha metido texto en ese texarea.

El caso es que he visto que con .remplace puedo buscar una cadena de texto y sustituirla por otro texto, pero claro solo busca una cadena de texto y yo tengo como 10 o 300 posibles cadenas distintas.

¿Sabeis si hay alguna forma de poder pasar a la vez varias cadenas de texto y que las remplace?

Yo ahora mismo lo que hago es sumar el texto nuevo al texto que ya existía usando esta función:

```
function PonTexto(id,ndatos,old) {
    var viejosdatos = $('#'+id).val();
    $.ajax({
    url: "Paginas/Textos.php?que=SacarTexto&id="+ndatos,
        type: "post",
        success: function(data) {
            $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : ndatos , sticky : false, type : 'success' });
            $('#'+id).val(viejosdatos + data);
            },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){ $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error al guardar '+ xhr.responseText, sticky : true, type : 'error' }); }
    });
}
```

y la función que estoy viendo que remplazaría el texto seria algo así:

```
$('#'+id).html(function(buscayreemplaza, reemplaza) {
        return reemplaza.replace('cadena', 'texto nuevo');
    });
```

en textos.php simplemente hay una consulta básica a mysql que devuelve un resultado con el texto nuevo. pero entiendo que tendría que cambiarlo por un array.

Y el textarea también es un texarea básico sin mayor historia.

¿se os ocurre alguna forma que pueda hacer esto?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

tocando código de aqui y de allá he conseguido llegar a esto:

```
 function PonTexto(id,ndatos) {
    var viejosdatos = $('#'+id).val();
    $.ajax({
    url: "Paginas/Textos?que=SacarTexto&id="+ndatos,
        type: "post",
        success: function(data) {
            $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : data , sticky : false, type : 'success' });
            var viejafp = data.split('-/'); //creo un array con la respuesta separado por un - arr[0] arr[1]
            console.log(viejafp);

            for (var val in viejafp)
            viejosdatos = viejosdatos.replace(new RegExp(val, "gi"), viejafp[val]);

            $('#'+id).val(viejosdatos);
            },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){ $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error al guardar '+ xhr.responseText, sticky : true, type : 'error' }); }
    });
}
```

pero no funciona creo que por el formato que le estoy dando en textos.php que es así:

```
foreach($Arrtexto as $Textos) { echo $Textos["Conf12"].":".$Textonuevo["Conf12"]."-/"; }
```

¿como podría formatear ese texto para que tenga un formato como este?

```
{"-":"X", "_":"Y", "\\+":"Z"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La tarea principal seria colocar los nuevos textos en un variable, considera que es un par **original:reemplazo** lo mas usado ahora es JSON.

Tu archivo **Textos.php** deberia retornar ese objeto `JSON`, para ellos puedes usar **json_encode(miArrayData)**;

```js
var texto = "Hola Pago al contado";
console.log(texto);
//este data seria el json retornado por Textos.php
var data=[{original: "Forma de pago: 20% del total a la confirmación del pedido y el resto antes de la entrega.", reemplazo: "Pago con PayPal a la cuenta XXX"}, {original: "Pago con PayPal a la cuenta XXX", reemplazo: "Pago con PayPal a la cuenta XXX"}, {original: "Cobro en cuenta de cliente", reemplazo: "Pago con PayPal a la cuenta XXX"}, {original: "Pago al contado", reemplazo: "Pago con PayPal a la cuenta XXX"}, {original: "Papelujo para mi", reemplazo: "Pago con PayPal a la cuenta XXX"}];

var nuevoTexto=replaceAll(texto,data);
console.log(nuevoTexto);

//////////////////////////////////
function replaceAll(texto,data){
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            if(texto.indexOf(data[i].original)<0 && texto.indexOf(data[i].reemplazo)<0){//agregando los no existentes
                texto=texto + data[i].reemplazo;
            }else{//reemplazando los existentes
                if(texto.indexOf(data[i].reemplazo)<0){
                    texto=texto.replace(new RegExp(data[i].original, 'g'),data[i].reemplazo);
                }else{
                    texto=texto.replace(new RegExp(data[i].original, 'g'),"");
                }
            }
    }
    return texto;
}
```

**PHP, array a json**

Arma tu respuesta de Base de Datos algo asi:

```
$data= array();
//usar un for para todos tus registros
array_push($data,array("original"=>$row['valorO'],"reemplazo"=>$row['valorR']));
array_push($data,array("original"=>$row['valorO'],"reemplazo"=>$row['valorR']));
array_push($data,array("original"=>$row['valorO'],"reemplazo"=>$row['valorR']));

//responder como json
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Al formatear en json el array me saca los datos que hay en la base de datos, pero no me deja poner detrás de los ":" el texto nuevo.  En la pregunta he puesto una posible solución que me resulta un poco mas sencilla que tu opción. Pero te agradezco de todas formas la ayuda.

Comment: en php debes usar un array (no ":"), luego al responder usa json_encode, he agregado eso a mi respuesta, revisalo

Comment: Ahora si :) solo me falta conseguir que el resultado de la función me lo ponga en $('#'+id).val(texto); y arreglado. Mil gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: eso ya esta sencillo. Suerte

Comment: Conseguido... no me había dado cuenta que ejecutabas la función en nuevoTexto. una duda mas que me surge... ¿sabes si hay forma de contar si ha sustituido algo? es que claro si no hay texto a sustituir lo tengo que agregar

Comment: entiendo que los resultados que no tengan con quien reemplazar deben ser agregados, es asi? ajustare la respuesta con eso

Comment: Si. :) de verdad que muchísimas gracias...

Comment: los agrego separados por coma ","?

Comment: No es necesaria la , el texto ya viene predefinido de mysql con el formato que debe tener

Comment: actualizada la respuesta

Comment: Genial... pone varias veces lo mismo, supongo que porque el array tiene muchos resultados. pero lo voy a intentar arreglar yo para que solo muestre uno... de verdad que muchísimas gracias :)....

Comment: debe ser, podrias hacer un distinct en tu consulta a base de datos para que no traiga repetidos. Suerte

Comment: No es que el array traiga repetidos, es que remplazo es siempre el mismo, que es el nuevo valor que paso por el select

Comment: vale, intentalo sino me comentas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65673/discussion-between-juliocpiro-and-killpe).